# Does gatsby remove proptypes by default?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm working in a new project with gatsby and reading about how to remove proptypes in production I found this: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/pull/14987 and my question how this works (if it works to my code and not just to the core of gatsby), is by default? or I should do something in order to remove all the proptypes in my code?

After run `gatsby build && gatsby serve` the proptypes are still there, I also tried to add a custom `.babelrc` and work directly with this plugin without results https://github.com/oliviertassinari/babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: yes, `PropTypes` are removed by default.

---

### TLTR

React/Gatsby applications works perfectly with `PropTypes`. The issue described is an open debate about if in production builds, these `PropTypes` should be removed since the code should be coherent, robust and, valid in `development` environment before it's deployed or build in the `production` environment.

If you assume that your code in `development` must be valid and `PropType`-friendly you can infer either that you can omit the `PropType` validation in `production` environment to reduce the bandwidth and improve the build/deploy times since the validation and review is done under `development`.

So, by default, your `PropTypes` will be removed in `production` build.

You don't need to add any extra configuration since, by default, Gatsby uses this `.babelrc` structure:

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",],
  "presets": [
    [
      "babel-preset-gatsby", //here your are adding the preset
      {
        "targets": {
          "browsers": [">0.25%", "not dead"]
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

And as you can see in this [GitHub pull-request](https://github.com/johno/gatsby/commit/f6feae5cd0ec5ee227b018d714ca012f9f2c28f8) and in [`babel-preset-gatsby`](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/babel-preset-gatsby/package.json#L23) dependencies the package is added in the default preset.

The changes added in this package only affects the core of your project, not the dependencies in `/node_modules`.

What are you seeing is a `DefaultProps`, that are a default value is for some reason (CMS issues for example) that props are not received by the React component and avoids the code break by providing a default value.

Summarizing:

- By default, your `PropTypes` will be removed in the `production` environment if you are using a default `.babelrc` integration.
- Your `node_modules` dependencies won't be affected by this addition of the Gatsby Babel preset.
- What are you seeing are `DefaultProps`, a way to avoid code-breaking while using `PropTypes` or data fetching issues, especially if they are required.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to reproduce your problem and it works for me.
I followed these steps:

1. Create new Gatsby site: `npx gatsby new gatsby-site`
2. Build site: `npm run build`
3. Run site: `npm run serve`

For example in the `Header` component propTypes are defined as the following:

```
Header.propTypes = {
  siteTitle: PropTypes.string,
}

Header.defaultProps = {
  siteTitle: ``,
}
```

When inspecting the finished site, you only see `defaultProps`, not `propTypes` which is correct

```js
var r = n("q1tI")
  , o = n.n(r)
  , i = n("Wbzz")
  , a = function(e) {
    var t = e.siteTitle;
    return o.a.createElement("header", {
        style: {
            background: "rebeccapurple",
            marginBottom: "1.45rem"
        }
    }, o.a.createElement("div", {
        style: {
            margin: "0 auto",
            maxWidth: 960,
            padding: "1.45rem 1.0875rem"
        }
    }, o.a.createElement("h1", {
        style: {
            margin: 0
        }
    }, o.a.createElement(i.Link, {
        to: "/",
        style: {
            color: "white",
            textDecoration: "none"
        }
    }, t))))
};
a.defaultProps = {
    siteTitle: ""
};
var c = a;
```

You can also verify by setting `siteTitle` to `PropTypes.number`

```
Header.propTypes = {
  siteTitle: PropTypes.number,
}
```

When running in development using `npm run develop` you will see a warning in your console

```
Failed prop type: Invalid prop `siteTitle` of type `string` supplied to `Header`, expected `number`.
```

You won't see this in production when running `npm run build && npm run serve`

Note: `propTypes` and `defaultProps` is something different.

Have you also checked your Gatsby version? Maybe you are running on an older version

I've tried using these versions (latest at the time of this post)

```
"dependencies": {
    "gatsby": "^2.24.26",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.4.14",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.4.21",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^3.2.21",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.3.10",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.6.24",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.3.23",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.5.12",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0"
  },
```